# Exclude blank column headers when sinking to sql-database

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an dynamic CSV file with alot of columns. I mapped the columns I want to get from the source side and sink it into an sql-database. I did this through a copy data activity in Azure Data Factory. However I'm getting the following error:

**ErrorCode=DelimitedTextColumnNameNotAllowNull,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The name of column index 236 is empty. Make sure column name is properly specified in the header**

There are blank column headers in the file. How can I exclude this? I tried searching Google and here for an similiar problem, but I couldn't find anything. The solutions I found was about excluding rows with empty values, however I only want to exclude the column headers with an empty value. It doesn't matter if the column itself has values in the rows.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two different ways of how I handled this in the past

- Use a data flow where you can parse the CSV and leave out specific columns. (this requires a data flow component and hence extra costs, which is why I prefer the second option)
- You can unmark "First Row as Header" in the dataset for the CSV in combination with "Skip Line Count" = 1 in the copy data activity. In this way, ADF won't read the first line and won't complain about it.

In the schema, you can now define which columns (by number) you want to map to which column in the database & which one you want to skip. In my example, the third column is skipped.

Schema:

[image: Schema]

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I understand it correctly --> all the columns in my CSV are being given numbers right? So If I want to have like column 1,2,3,40,52 and 68, then I need to give the numbers of the columns in the mapping with the name I want it to have in my SQL table? If so then I have an problem, because these are daily csv-files we get and tomorrow I can have a column added between 52 and 68, which means that my mapping doesn't sink the right columns anymore.

Comment: That is correct, each column will be given a number and you can map it towards the name of your column in the database. I sadly don't know how you can solve the changing columns issue,...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the ask , but I just want to share that even if you do not have a header in a column in a CSV file and you select the first row is header , ADF will be add a header . See the snapshot below

[image]

[image]

So one solution which you may think of changing to pipeline from

CSV -> SQL

to

CSV -> CSV ( to add the header ) -> SQL

Now coming back to the addition of column  say column 54 . This is anyways a bigger problem as you will have to alter the SQL table also to accomdate this new column 54 correct ?

If I were you I could have used a AUTO CREATE Table option , that way ADF will create table as per the CSV  . Once I have the data in the staging table < i can compare the same with the actual table and make some logic ( since the data is in SQL may a proc will do the trick )

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply. I don't need to alter the table as I don't want to add the new columns that can come every day if they start to add  new columns. I pre-mapped 30 columns I want to have (with the column headers) but I can't sink it because of the columns without a header at the end. I don't want those columns in my table in SQL.

EDIT: I understand your reply. So you say put a step between the copy data activity --> copy data first to an CSV and sink it in your staging-table, alter the table and insert the columns you want in a new table and drop the other one (via stored proc)